# Validate on Blur

Tags: knockout-validation

I've created a JSFiddle to help demonstrate my question: http://jsfiddle.net/jeffreyrswenson/CrYWn/5/

Here's what I'd like to see:

- Messages should not appear when page loads.
- Messages should appear when submit button is pushed.
- Messages should appear after input value is changed and user leaves element. (Tabs or clicks to next field)
- Messages should appear after user leave an input without changing.(For example a field is required and the user tabs through the field, but doesn't enter a value.  I'd like the validation message to appear when this happens.)

The first four work as I'd expect.  Is the last item possible and if so, what do I need to change to enable that behavior?

HTML:

```
<label>First name:
<input data-bind='value: firstName' />
</label>
<br/>
<label>Last name:
    <input data-bind='value: lastName' />
</label>
<br/>
<button type="button" data-bind='click: submit'>Submit</button>
<br/>
<span data-bind='text: errors().length'></span> errors
```

ViewModel:

```
var viewModel = function () {
       ko.validation.configure({
           decorateElement: true,
           registerExtenders: true,
           messagesOnModified: true,
           insertMessages: true,
           parseInputAttributes: true,
           messageTemplate: null
       });

       this.firstName = ko.observable().extend({
           required: true
       });
       this.lastName = ko.observable().extend({
           required: true,
           pattern: {
               message: 'Hey this doesnt match my pattern',
               params: '^[A-Z0-9]+$'
           }
       });

       this.submit = function () {
           if (this.errors().length == 0) {
               alert('Thank you.');
           } else {
               this.errors.showAllMessages();
           }
       };
       this.errors = ko.validation.group(this);
   };
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You just need to use the standard `valueUpdate` option of the [`value` binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/value-binding.html) where you can specify additional events to trigger your property change and with that the validation.

So you just need to add the `valueUpdate: "blur"` setting on your bindings:

```
<label>First name:
    <input data-bind='value: firstName, valueUpdate: "blur"' />
</label>
<br/>
<label>Last name:
    <input data-bind='value: lastName, valueUpdate: "blur"' />
</label>
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/29ucZ/).

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I needed the value to update after key down because I was making some fields visible if the input had a value. I wanted the underlying value to update but didn't want the validation to show until the user tabbed to the next input.

A bit of CSS and a couple of bindings is what worked for me:

CSS:

```
div.validationWrapper.standard-focus.has-focus .validationMessage 
{
    display: none;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="validationWrapper standard-focus" data-bind="css: { 'has-focus': MyObservableHasFocus() }">
    <input class="standard-focus" type="text" data-bind="hasFocus: MyObservableHasFocus, value: MyObservable, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'" />
</div>
```

Knockout:

```
self.MyObservable = ko.observable('').extend({/* Your validation here */});
self.MyObservableHasFocus = ko.observable(false);
```

The result is an observable that updates it's value after key up and shows the validation message after it loses focus.